# REthinkdb table is not showing in the interface

Tags: database, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a rethinkdb with databse wich is contain near about 250 database each database contain 7 table. The current size of data is nearly 11gb. The problem is from the admin interface i am unable to see the database and tables. it gives me error like this

> Query terminated by an unknown cause in:
>       r.db("rethinkdb").table("db_config").filter(function(var_22) { return var_22("name").ne("rethinkdb"); }).map(function(var_23) { return {"name": var_23("name"), "id": var_23("id"), .............

Please help me. please i amfacig a great problem. I am attaching a picture

[image]

Comment: Error come up when i try to click on Tables menu. My database running and i am able to insert data by node js. For visual presentation please see the image which i have attached in above post.

Comment: Hi Abdus, can you provide the full query you attempted which resulted in this error? As well as where you are hosting your DB and a little bit more about the data set you're accessing?

Comment: The webui hasn't been tested with this many tables. I'm guessing something in the admin api is hitting the array limit

Answer (score 1):

The web UI is timing out while trying to retrieve the data due to the high number of tables.

There isn't much you can do at this point, apart from querying the system tables directly with a different client. See http://rethinkdb.com/docs/system-tables/ for details on how to use the system tables.

The timeout is specific to the web UI, and using another client (node.js, Python etc.) should work fine.

We have two relevant issues open about improving this on our issue tracker:

1. Getting rid of the timeout: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2316
2. Fixing the error message. It should mention the timeout rather than saying "by an unknown cause": https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5113

Comment: One thing you could do is increase the timeout and compile from source: See http://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ for compilation instructions. You'll need to change the value in this line: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/v2.2.x/src/rdb_protocol/query_server.hpp#L37